# found nil while unwrapping optional in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I know this is probably a simple one just not sure what I'm missing here need a fresh pair of eyes. I understand here that I need to unwrap which I'm trying to do but it  keeps failing, I'm doing something wrong can any help? heres the code (I'm probably gonna kick myself)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var currentLocation = self.locations[indexPath.row]
    var displayLocation = currentLocation["User"] as! PFObject

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if let display = displayLocation as PFObject? {

    cell.textLabel?.text = display["currentLocation"] as? String
    }

    return cell

}
```

sorry guys forgot to mention its failing on this line

```
var displayLocation = currentLocation["User"] as! PFObject
```

Comment: At what line you are getting the error?

Comment: failing on this line buddy

Comment: var displayLocation = currentLocation["User"] as! PFObject

Comment: Add that in your question.:)

Comment: That means you are casting   `currentLocation["User"]` to `PFObject` with `as!` which is not possible.

Comment: no worries Ive changed to     as?    just pulling back anything from my database (not getting the unwrapping error though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you are casting `currentLocation["User"]` to `PFObject` with `as!` which is not possible. Because may be your `currentLocation["User"]` is `nil`.

And if it is `nil` you can not cast it as `PFObject`.

Answer (score 0):

The `currentLocation` dictionary lacks a value for the key "User", or the value is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple, like this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: 
NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var currentLocation = self.locations[indexPath.row]    
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if let displayLocation = currentLocation["User"] as? PFObject {
        cell.textLabel?.text = displayLocation["currentLocation"] as? String
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: NSString is not a subtype of PFObject

Comment: Is that in this line "    cell.textLabel?.text = display["currentLocation"] as? String
"

Comment: print the displayLocation dictionary in console and paste here